# User Control Does not appear in ToolBox in VS2005

Tags: visual-studio-2005

When I create a user control in VS2005, it does not appear in toolbox. My project
has quite huge number of User Control so the workaround to drag/drop usercontrol dll
to toolbox is not a possible solution.
Can any one suggest how I can get rid of this VS2005 bug.
Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

There is an option in VS 2005 that will cause VS to automatically populate the toolbox with any controls you compile as part of your solution.

To enable this option, select the **Tools | Options | Windows Forms Designer** and then set **AutoToolboxPopulate** to True

Comment: Oh man, I know this was posted a while ago but I must say thanks.

Comment: Applies to VS 2008 as well! Thanks!